# How to extract exceptions from java log file?

Tags: bash, parsing, logging, trace

I have a huge log file with a lot of exceptions and I need to extract full stack traces and few lines before and after it. It will be perfect if tool for this is bash script.
example:

```
    $16.02.2012 16:04:34 *INFO * [main] InitialContextInitializer: Reference bound: rmirepository (InitialContextInitializer.java, line 203) 
16.02.2012 16:04:34 *ERROR* [main] StandaloneContainerInitializedListener: Error of StandaloneContainer initialization (StandaloneContainerInitializedListener.java, line 109) 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate component key=org.exoplatform.services.jcr.ext.script.groovy.GroovyScript2RestLoader type=org.exoplatform.services.jcr.ext.script.groovy.GroovyScript2RestLoader found at file:/home/roman/reports/backup/1.14.7-5636/rdbms/single/exo-tomcat_1.14.7-5636/exo-configuration.xml
    at org.exoplatform.container.jmx.MX4JComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(MX4JComponentAdapter.java:134)
    at org.exoplatform.container.management.ManageableComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ManageableComponentAdapter.java:68)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ConcurrentPicoContainer.getInstance(ConcurrentPicoContainer.java:468)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ConcurrentPicoContainer.getComponentInstancesOfType(ConcurrentPicoContainer.java:366)
    at org.exoplatform.container.CachingContainer.getComponentInstancesOfType(CachingContainer.java:111)
    at org.exoplatform.container.LifecycleVisitor.visitContainer(LifecycleVisitor.java:151)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ConcurrentPicoContainer.accept(ConcurrentPicoContainer.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.AbstractPicoVisitor.traverse(AbstractPicoVisitor.java:32)
    at org.exoplatform.container.LifecycleVisitor.traverse(LifecycleVisitor.java:90)
    at org.exoplatform.container.LifecycleVisitor.start(LifecycleVisitor.java:170)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ConcurrentPicoContainer.start(ConcurrentPicoContainer.java:554)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ExoContainer.start(ExoContainer.java:266)
    at org.exoplatform.container.StandaloneContainer$3.run(StandaloneContainer.java:178)
    at org.exoplatform.container.StandaloneContainer$3.run(StandaloneContainer.java:175)
    at org.exoplatform.commons.utils.SecurityHelper.doPrivilegedAction(SecurityHelper.java:291)
    at org.exoplatform.container.StandaloneContainer.getInstance(StandaloneContainer.java:174)
    at org.exoplatform.container.StandaloneContainer.getInstance(StandaloneContainer.java:129)
    at org.exoplatform.ws.frameworks.servlet.StandaloneContainerInitializedListener.contextInitialized(StandaloneContainerInitializedListener.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate component key=org.exoplatform.services.jcr.RepositoryService type=org.exoplatform.services.jcr.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl found at file:/home/roman/reports/backup/1.14.7-5636/rdbms/single/exo-tomcat_1.14.7-5636/exo-configuration.xml
    at org.exoplatform.container.jmx.MX4JComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(MX4JComponentAdapter.java:134)
    at org.exoplatform.container.management.ManageableComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ManageableComponentAdapter.java:68)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ConcurrentPicoContainer.getInstance(ConcurrentPicoContainer.java:468)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ConcurrentPicoContainer.getComponentInstanceOfType(ConcurrentPicoContainer.java:422)
    at org.exoplatform.container.CachingContainer.getComponentInstanceOfType(CachingContainer.java:139)
    at org.exoplatform.container.ExoContainer.createComponent(ExoContainer.java:407)
    at org.exoplatform.container.jmx.MX4JComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(MX4JComponentAdapter.java:96)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: You need to provide some more info, perhaps a log and the expected output. As a start have a look at `grep` and the `-A, `-B` switched that describes how many lines after/before a match that should be displayed.

Comment: what dose the output looks like?

Answer (score 7):

Use `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    previous = "";
}
/^\tat / {
    if( previous != "" ) {
        print previous;
    previous = "";
    }
    print;
    next;
}
 { previous = $0; }
```

should do the trick. In a nutshell, look for the pattern `\tat` (tab, at, blank) which almost always is used in a stack trace.

If you have many exceptions, then you can use maps (associative arrays in AWK's lingo) to save part of the exception message and then do statistics (like which exception happens the most).

Comment: Thanks a lot! but awk is new for me and yes I have many exceptions can you please show example with maps? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most of line in Java exception block are start with TAB delimiter.

So to get all exceptions from a huge log file you can use grep TAB delimiter.

Use following command to grep all exceptions from a file:

```
**$ grep -P -A 15 -B 15 "^\t" inputLogFile**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command
`grep -B 10 -A 100 "Caused By" app.log` -->this will give all the java exception logged in application log file. You can change string if you want to find specific exceptions.
https://www.techiedelight.com/java-program-search-exceptions-huge-log-file-on-server/

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this,

```
=======
grep -B20 -A20 ^'$16.02.2012 16:04:34' <path/to/log/file>
=======

Where 
-B20 -- will display 20 lines before the line where the match was found.
-A20 -- will display 20 lines after the line where the match was found.
```